# How to create a new column in a DataFrame based on values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns, where I want to create a third column based on the values of these two columns. That is, the third column should say original if the values in col_a equal the values in col_b and replica otherwise.

Example:

```
col_a col_b 
1234  1234  
1235  1234  
1236  1234  
1237  1234  
1321  1321
```

Expected Outcome:

```
col_a col_b type
1234  1234  original
1235  1234  replica
1236  1234  replica
1431  1431  original
1321  1431  replica
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
type = []

for x in df['col_a'] and y in df['col_b']:
    if x == y:
        type.append('original') 
    else:
        type.append('replica') 
        
df['type'] = [type]
```

I am a newbie in Python, so I might be overlooking some crucial basic steps.

Comment: Try `for x, y in zip(df['col_a'], df['col_b'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['type'] = np.where(df['col_a'].eq(df['col_b']), 'original', 'replica')
```

output:

```
   col_a  col_b      type
0   1234   1234  original
1   1235   1234   replica
2   1236   1234   replica
3   1237   1234   replica
4   1321   1321  original
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution. We use `.loc` to match the rows that met a condition (say, `df["col_a"] == df["col_b"]`) and apply the value `"original"` on the column "type":

```py
equal_rows = df["col_a"] == df["col_b"]
df.loc[equal_rows, "type"] = "original"
df.loc[~equal_rows, "type"] = "replica" # "Not equal rows" = Rows that are different
```

Comment: this works, but it's too bad to perform the (almost) same comparison twice ;)

Comment: Changed it to store the comparison in a Series and then use the series to index the dataframe, but it still requires two lookups